# Mysql/Mariadb backup from non-bootable system

Tags: mysql, backup, mariadb, backup-restoration

My working server crashed, more precise, my HDD got bad sectors.
What is proper method to make a backup from non-working server and restore it later on newly installed server?

Any set of files I need to copy/replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say which OS/Distro but in general

- /etc/my.cnf
- /etc/my.cnf.d/* (if it exists)
- /var/lib/mysql/*

You may want to take a look at the config files after you have copied them from the disk to check that the datadir is correct.

Comment: It's Centos, dont remember if 6 or 7. I think 7. I assume /var;ib/mysql/* holds all database data, keys, indexes, schemas etc?

Comment: That is the default datadir.

Comment: Don't forget to `chown` recursively `/var/lib/mysql` content, importing this to your replacement instance.

Comment: Can't make image of partition. Currently `tar`ing all i Can. Haven't changed chown/chmod to files, but fired `tar` with `sudo tar`. hope it will have all privileges to copy files...

Comment: *"Can't make image of partition."* That doesn't make sense.  Use `dd_rescue`.